# Where can I post Gadget related issues?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question for comparing Iphone and Android where can I post questions related to that?

I have tried to search on Area51 site a proposal related to a gadget related site but the question is closed 2 years ago.

Comment: Is there a _specific_ feature you'd like to compare? Or is it basically Android vs. iPhone? If the latter, there's really no site that deals with that type of question. If the prior, could you be a little more specific?

Comment: @TimPost : Only the basic comparisons

Comment: That's probably something you'd want to take to a popular forum that covers the topic, though I'd imagine it's been covered in many places several times. We don't do so well with compare / contrast, or other mostly discussion topics.

Comment: @TimPost : I know that. I just wanted To post it in stack exchange site because the users are quick to answer and clearer. Also we can comment on their answers, helping me to get the appropriate answer